# jenkins job fails when i run full django tests

Tags: python, django, testing, jenkins, pylint

When i run the tests on my local machine everything works fine

when i run only my apps tests everything works

but when i run the full set of tests in jenkins it fails,
and the even stranger thing is all the tests pass.

Im guessing it has something to do with pylint, but im not sure.

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions on whats happening?

```
+ python nexus7/manage.py jenkins
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................s............................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 473 tests in 12.744s

OK (skipped=1)
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nexus7/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_jenkins/management/commands/__init__.py", line 81, in handle
    if test_runner.run_tests(test_labels):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/test/simple.py", line 384, in run_tests
    self.teardown_test_environment()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_jenkins/runner.py", line 253, in teardown_test_environment
    signals.teardown_test_environment.send(sender=self)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_jenkins/tasks/run_pylint.py", line 43, in teardown_test_environment
    lint.Run(args, reporter=ParseableTextReporter(output=self.output), exit=False)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 929, in __init__
    linter.check(args)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 542, in check
    self.check_astng_module(astng, walker, rawcheckers)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 615, in check_astng_module
    walker.walk(astng)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/utils.py", line 558, in walk
    cb(astng)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/cb5c943f/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/checkers/variables.py", line 176, in leave_module
    elt_name = elt.value
AttributeError: 'Name' object has no attribute 'value'
Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Skipping Cobertura coverage report as build was not UNSTABLE or better ...
Recording test results
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: It's not the tests, but the `Virtualenv Builder` build step that is marking the build as failed

Comment: According to the stacktrace, pylint fails to run. Are you able to run the same command that Jenkins runs, if you log in manually to the test machine as the Jenkins user?

Comment: @Christopher not easily, i currently dont have access to the machine